# Why wont my button redirect to another page after a confirmation alert?

Tags: javascript, html, button

When I click on my button it shows the alert as normal but if i click OK, it won't redirect me to the requested page.

My code says:

```html
<button onclick="return myFunction('Jane McDonald')" href="people/janemcdonald.html">
```

and

```js
function myFunction(person) {
            if (confirm("Do you want to go to " + person + "'s profile?")) {
                return true;
           } else {
                return false;
           }
      }
```

The alert shows as normal but if I click OK it doesn't redirect me to the page.

Comment: errr `href` on a `button`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: How about just writing a normal link?

Answer (score 0):

1- Change `myFunction` code:

```
function myFunction(person) {
    if (confirm("Do you want to go to " + person + "'s profile?")) {
         window.location.href = "people/janemcdonald.html";;
   } else {
        return false;
   }
}
```

2- Delete `href` path fom html

```
<button onclick="return myFunction('Jane McDonald')">Redirect</button>
```

Now you can confirm `ok` and the page will redirect to the new path.